# When making an item, is it allowed to salvage other items to reduce the cost?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting

Say I am an artificer (base class) and I am crafting a magic item for which I need 600 GP worth of raw materials. It doesn't state what these materials need to be- Just that it should be worth 600 GP. 
I have a magic item with me worth 1000 GP. This means that its craft cost entailed 500 GP worth of materials. Could I 'salvage' this item and earn 500 from it to use on my new item?
Or, even better but less likely, would I be able to get the full price?

Comment: By *artificer* do you mean the base class or just a dude who makes stuff? By *item* do you mean *magic item*? Similarly, by *materials* do you mean *raw materials for mundane crafting* or *raw materials for magic item creation*? (The question never mentions magic and doesn't differentiate between *magic item creation* and *mundane crafting* and is tagged both *magic-items* and *crafting* so I want to be sure what you're after for here. The differences can be pronounced.)

Comment: I did not realise all these differences mattered. I am talking about an actual artificer, I mean raw materials, and the item I am currently crafting is a construct, but I suppose any good old magic item would be the same as far as this question is concerned.

Comment: The big difference is in the price of raw materials for magic item creation (typically one-half the finished value of the magic item) and the price of raw materials for mundane item crafting (typically one-third the finished value of the mundane item). Other details are less important, but being able to address your concerns precisely is easier than addressing a bunch of stuff generally.

Answer (score 6):

The *Player's Handbook* on [Item Creation Feats](http://dndsrd.net/feats.html#item-creation-feats) on Raw Materials says

> Creating a magic item requires costly components, most of which are consumed in the process. The cost of these materials equals half the cost of the item.…
>
> Using an item creation feat also requires access to a laboratory or magical workshop, special tools, and so on. A character generally has access to what he or she needs unless unusual circumstances apply (if the character is traveling far from home, for instance). (88)

Despite this description saying that creating a magic item expends only *most* of the raw materials, every *Player's Handbook* item creation feat says specifically that raw materials are *used up* by the item creation process, hence leaving behind *no* raw materials and creating finished goods—the resultant magic item.

This means that unless the DM rules that magic items *are* raw materials for *another* magic item's creation—and I've not heard of a DM making such a ruling—, a magic item *can't* be used as raw materials for one or more *other* magic items. (Some special abilities like the benefit of the feat Ancestral Relic (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 39, 40), however, provide alternatives.) For example, it's typically impossible to use 20 *divine scrolls of [cure light wounds](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#cure-light-wounds)* [conj] (*PH* 215-6) (1st-level spell at caster level 2) (25 gp; 0 lbs.) and 10 *arcane scrolls of cure light wounds* (1st-level spell at caster level 2) (50 gp; 0 lbs.) as raw materials for a [*phylactery of faithfulness*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#phylactery-of-faithfulness) (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 264) (1,000 gp; 0 lbs.).

So anyone—not *just* an artificer—that wants to create a magic item probably needs actual raw materials to do so. The nature of these raw materials depends upon the campaign. The DM here has vast leeway.

- The DM can rule that raw materials are specific to a certain magic item. For instance, if a creator wants to create a *phylactery of faithfulness*the creator needs to buy 500 gp of *phylactery of faithfulness* raw materials. There can be no substitutions. A creator that changes his mind about making a magic item after buying the raw materials but  before creating the magic item can sell back the raw materials (presumably at full price).
- The DM can rule that raw materials are specific to a particular item creation feat. For example, a scribe can buy 100 gp of raw materials for the item creation feat [Scribe Scroll](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#scribe-scroll) (*PH* 99-100) and draw from that supply of raw materials whenever it comes time to scribe a scroll, not worrying that what's needed is instead raw materials for a *divine scroll of cure light wounds* (1st-level spell at caster level 1) for the creator's druid spell and completely *different* raw materials for an *arcane scroll of cure light wounds* (1st-level spell at caster level 2) for the same creator's bard spell.
- The DM can rule that raw materials are *just* raw materials and completely interchangeable. For example, a creator that invests 1,000 gp in raw materials can use those raw materials to create a *phylactery of faithfulness*, 20 *divine scrolls of cure light wounds* (1st-level spell at caster level 2), and 10 *arcane scrolls of cure light wounds* (1st-level spell at caster level 2).

Other possibilities abound, of course, and the DM can mix these and others depending on the feat, setting, or whatever—I can imagine a setting wherein raw materials for the feats [Craft Magic Arms and Armor](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#craft-magic-arms-and-armor) and Scribe Scroll are (probably separately) universal for those feats, but a creator must buy raw materials for other magic items specifically, and one magic-rich town sells generic raw materials that can be used to create *any* magic item. While that sounds to this DM really complicated, this player knows where his PC would visit frequently.

***Note:** The* Eberron Campaign Setting *base class artificer's supernatural ability retain essence (32) only allows the artificer to destroy a magic item to add item's [XP cost](http://dndsrd.net/feats.html#item-creation-xp-cost) to the artificer's craft reserve. No gp is gained from using the ability retain essence.*

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, a lot of this is going to come down to the specific circumstances of the campaign, characters, and the items in question. There are no answers that apply in all cases.

#### Bare Minimum: Given a large enough town, you should be able to “salvage” the item for materials equal to half its value

Where a “large enough town” is defined as one large enough that you can readily find a buyer for the item you own, and a seller for the materials necessary to make the item you want. Then you can just sell the item you own, taking half its value in hard currency, and buy materials you need with that currency.

#### Specific cases may do better or worse than that

The sell-what-I-have-and-buy-what-I-need approach should be work in every campaign and for every pair of items, *if* you can find that “large enough town.” But a campaign may not have any town large enough to buy or source materials for some particular items, and there may be other problems with this approach. In campaigns that are particular sticklers for realism, just transporting sufficient hard currency to buy the materials for a high-level magical item becomes quite prohibitive (a hundred thousand gold pieces is a literal *ton* of gold). There may be cases where the item you have is literally worthless for the purposes of making another item, because it cannot be sold at all.

On the flip side, the DM is free to rule that some of the components of the item are more directly useful than their raw sale value for creating some other specific item. Maybe they rule that a major component in a particular staff is a large, magically-imbued crystal—that happens to be the same sort of crystal used in the wand you have, so if you just pry that off (destroying the wand), you could use that as a big portion of the staff. Or maybe your chain shirt can be used as the chain portion of your full-plate, so you can just use it as-is and add plates over it (so its full value counts against the cost of the full-plate). Whatever. But all such cases are purely up to the DM on a case-by-case basis.

#### No class offers features that help significantly here

The artificer comes closest with retain essence, but retain essence only helps paying for the XP costs of magic items, not the gold cost. Besides the artificer, there really is just nothing relevant for this process out there.